# How to get all the WebElements from an angular application using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver

Basically, I want to get all the WebElements on a webpage. I am using the below which is working fine for static HTML pages.

```
List<WebElement> all = wd.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));
```

But on angular pages I am not able to get all the elements ( due to the directive used in HTML page ).

The page View Source is something like this :

```
<html>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Endgame is to create a tool to generate locators on a page, I am using Java and selenium-wd for it. If any better approach, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Query all the elements of the page, then use your app discriminer (usually `app-`) to sort the Angular elements. Something like this :

```js
const allElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('*')];
const angularElements = allElements.filter(el => el.tagName.toLowerCase().startsWith('app-'));

console.log(
  angularElements.length + ' Angular elements found : ' + angularElements
  .map(el => el.tagName.toLowerCase()).join(', ')
);
```

```html
<app-root>
  <app-component>
    <app-child-one></app-child-one>
    <app-child-two></app-child-two>
  </app-component>
</app-root>

<div></div>
<mat-select></mat-select>
```

Comment: I am already getting the angular elements, i want the elements from the HTML source that angular generates.

Comment: @rogue_leader not sure what you're talking about, but those are the elements generated by angular once compiled.

Comment: These <app-*> directives have the HTML defined which render on the page, I want to get those Elements.

Eg. <app-child-one> might render a form.

Comment: @rogue_leader so the `innerHTML` of the `app-*` elements ?

Comment: Yes, I want the webelements inside the angular directive.

Comment: [`parent.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) should do the trick then

Comment: I already tried that ( using JavascriptExecutor ) but it is becoming complicated due to the depth ( I am saving the childnodes in a list of webelements )